# How to send email or do something after a time period without action from user

Tags: parse-platform, automatic-updates

I have a question about how to do something after a specific time period. For example, a buyer buys some shoes in my app. I uploaded his information to Parse. Then, the seller can receive notification that his shoes are sold. But, if seller does not do anything within a period like 24 hours, I want to cancel this transaction automatically without the action from buyer and seller. Should I implement this in Parse or in my app?

Answer (score 0):

This should be implemented as a cloud job (it could run repeatedly and scan for work or it could be once per day, repeatedly is safer given the runtime constraints). It is a server task. You shouldn't need to rely on any user triggering some logic in a client app to have this processing completed.

Comment: And post I can follow to doing that?

Comment: The parse website has a guide